# Using Fancybox version 2 - When Closing 2nd fancybox reopen first fancybox instead of simply closing

Tags: html, fancybox

Using Fancybox version 2 supplied by http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support

I want to open a fancybox from my main page, but within that 1st fancy box a second fancybox can be called. But when that 2nd fancy box is closed. Rather than simply closing(pressing X in the corner or by pressing Esc) it I want it to reopen the first fancybox. How do I do this?

Thank you - I have searched the internet for an answer but found answers regarding my query applying to previous versions of fancybox not the new version (2.0)...

My code is below:

Main Page-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./source/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
                Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
            */

            $('.fancybox').fancybox();

            /*
                Different effects
            */

            // Change title type, overlay opening speed and opacity
            $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
                helpers: {
                    title : {
                        type : 'outside'
                    },
                    overlay : {
                        speedIn : 500,
                        opacity : 0.95
                    }
                }
            });


            /*
                Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
            */

            $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                closeBtn  : false,
                arrows    : false,
                nextClick : true,

                helpers : { 
                    thumbs : {
                        width  : 50,
                        height : 50
                    }
                }
            });
});
</script>
    <a href="1stFancyBox.html" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax">1st Fancy Box</a>
</html>
```

1stFancyBox.html -

```
<html>
<a href="2ndFancyBox.html" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax">2nd FancyBox</a>
</html>
```

2ndFancyBox.html -

```
<html>
<body>
Hellloooooooooo</body>
</html>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create two scripts, one for each link
so in the `main` page you have:

```
<a href="1stFancyBox.html" class="fancybox1 fancybox.ajax">1st Fancy Box</a>
```

Notice that class is now `fancybox1` ... then the script tha fires the first fancybox.

```
$(".fancybox1").fancybox();
```

Inside `1stFancyBox.html` you can have this link

```
<a href="2ndFancyBox.html" class="fancybox2 fancybox.ajax">2nd FancyBox</a>
```

Notice that class is now `fancybox2`

Also in the `main` page add the script that fires the second fancybox (from within the first fancybox):

```
$(".fancybox2").fancybox({
 afterClose: function(){
  $(".fancybox1").trigger("click");
 }
});
```

The script above will fire the *first* fancybox after closing the *second* fancybox regardless the content of `2ndFancyBox.html`.

**UPDATE**: I added a [DEMO here](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/STACK_openFBfromFBandReopen1st_10jun12.html)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, when I close 2nd fancy box page just goes dark... Please help

I've done everything you stated here, replaced classes. Changed $(".fancybox").fancybox(); to $(".fancybox1").fancybox();

And added
$(".fancybox2").fancybox({
 afterClose: function(){
  $(".fancybox1").trigger("click");
 }
});
 within fancybox1 on main page...

$(".fancybox1").fancybox({

$(".fancybox2").fancybox({
 afterClose: function(){
  $(".fancybox1").trigger("click");
 }
});
});

Comment: It seems that you mixed it up a bit, see my update where I added a DEMO. Feel free to analyze and compare the source code. The fancybox scripts should be on the main page only. Links and content vary on the 1st and 2nd html files.