# Opening another fancybox on a page after closing the previous one

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using fancybox version 2.1.5. When I open the fancybox I noticed the **.fancybox-wrap** div is inside the **.fancybox-overlay** div. If I open another fancybox on the same page the .fancybox-overlay div is now outside and above the .fancybox-wrap div.

My definition of the first and the second fancybox are the same and as follows:

```
$.fancybox({
    href        : '#my_div',
    autoSize    : true,
    fitToView   : false,
    padding     : 0,
    fixed       : true,
    autoCenter  : false,
    topRatio    : 0.5,
});
```

If the .fancybox-wrap div is inside the .fancybox-overlay div and I scroll the page , when the fancybox content is larger than the window only the fancybox scrolls the background content remains static

However when it is outside the .fancybox-overlay when i scroll both the fancybox and the content behind it scrolls.

How do I prevent the page from scrolling behind.

When you inspect the [DEMO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973380/using-fancybox-version-2-when-closing-2nd-fancybox-reopen-first-fancybox-inste) in this question the wrap div is outside the overlay div as compared to the demos on the fancybox website.

Comment: Do I need to run a $.fancybox.close(); before opening the next fancybox?

Comment: you don't need to run `$.fancybox.close();` to open the second since the first will be automatically closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the [DEMO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10973380/using-fancybox-version-2-when-closing-2nd-fancybox-reopen-first-fancybox-inste) you make reference to (my demo) uses fancybox v2.0.6; things have changed since then.

Second, the fact that `.fancybox-wrap` div is either inside or outside the `.fancybox-overlay` depends on the helpers overlay status :

The **default** value is `true` like :

```
helpers: {
    overlay : {
        locked: true
    }
}
```

... so the `.fancybox-wrap` div will be **INSIDE** the `.fancybox-overlay` div.

On the other hand, if you set the value to `false` in your custom script, then the `.fancybox-wrap` div will be **OUTSIDE**  the `.fancybox-overlay` div.

**NOTICE** that in the second case (`false`), you will be able to scroll the page behind fancybox.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbJsJ/1/)** using v2.1.5

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work if you open another fancybox from inside the first fancybox http://jsfiddle.net/ZbJsJ/11/. I have 2 modal boxes 1 and 2. When I open modal1 with overlay locked: true the background remains fixed. However if i open modal2 from inside modal1  the background now gets a scroll.
Both modal1 and modal2 have the same fancybox definitions. Why does the page scroll when modal2 opens? Also when modal2 opens the .wrap div is outside the overlay div even though the definition has overlay locked: true

Comment: @Neil : I am afraid my friend that you just discovered a bug. I opened the [issue #672](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/672)

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub, the author of FancyBox suggests trying FancyBox 3 beta to see if the issue is resolved. It doesn't feel ready for prime-time to me (at the time of writing this comment), so I've resolved the bug in the following way:

```
beforeShow : function() {
  // Move the wrap manually into overlay
  $(".fancybox-wrap").appendTo(".fancybox-overlay");

  // Add the missing classes to <html>
  $("html").addClass("fancybox-margin fancybox-lock");
},
```

I'm using overlay **locked: true** and **autoCenter: false** to lock the background and get the desired positioning.

Finally, when opening FancyBoxes with ajax content lower down the page, it seems FancyBox does not reset the CSS **top** value and I wasn't able to override using jQuery in the callbacks, so I resolved to force this in the FancyBox CSS:

```
.fancybox-opened {z-index: 8030; top: 20px !important;}
```

This will open all FancyBoxes, first and subsequent ones, 20px from the top of the viewport at any point down the page.